# How to import System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<object> so I can cast HttpResponseMessage.Content to it?

Tags: c#, .net, casting

For my unit tests I want to cast the content of my HttpResponseMessage to the correct type, so I can access it's Value property, like so:

`var content = result.Content as System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<object>;`

When I debug I can see the type is this:

`System.Net.Http.HttpContent {System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<object>}`

However, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'ObjectContent<>' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

But it's in my project references and when I import that assembly with the `using` keyword it is recognised, so it's definitely there.

When I import the namespace I get the following error message though:

> The type or namespace name 'ObjectContent<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also tried it writing only `ObjectContent`, without `<object>`, but that gives the same error.

Comment: note to self, it might be due to needing to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, will check back when i can connect to nuget again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`, after that the compiler could recognise `ObjectContent`.